# Need to show the down arrow in dropdown list in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

Working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. I am created a dropdown using the select `asp-for` tag helper. But I am not seeing a dropdown down arrow.  Also I want to set the top  or particular value selected by default.

Below is code and image of a dropdown

```
<div class="col-sm-3">             
    <select name="products" class="form-control " 
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ddaircraft,"id","name"))">
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

---

Action Method code for ViewBag:

```
Public IActionResult Index()
{
 var countries= _countries.getCountries();
        //add an country item on the top of list. 
        countries.Insert(0, new Aircraft { Registration="0"});

        //i used the country.name for value and item
        var ddforAircraft =  from country in countries
        select new { id = country.name, name=country.name=="0"?"Item List":country.name };

       // ddforAircraft.Append(new { id = "0", name = "" });
        ViewBag.ddaircraft = ddforAircraft;
       return View()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, after Tiny Wang pointed me to the direction which really helped me to search the answer.

In order to see the dropdown down arrow I added a css class "form-select" without removing anything and I started to see the down arrow

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">             
            <select name="products" class="form-control form-select-sm form-select " asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ddaircraft,"id","name"))">
            </select>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Missing dropdown arrow resulted from the class `form-control`, I test in my side and I found the arrow can be seen by default until I add `class="form-control "` to my code:

[image]

removing this 2 options then the arrow appeared again, so it proved to relate to the class, you may need to update the style:

[image]

Then I use Jquery to change the default selected option when page is loading in my code, my selector has Id `Country`, then change the value(ListItem.Value):

```
<select asp-for="Country" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Countries, nameof(ListItem.Value), nameof(ListItem.Text)))">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
         $("#Country").val('Canada')
    </script>
}
```